# PDO Insert not working with bindParam

Tags: php, pdo

I am currently using PDO to connect to my database and it works, but when a user logs in, I want it to check if the user's id is already in a row, I have already done this in the code below:

```
<?php
require 'steamauth/steamauth.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {

$username = "Unknown";
$avatar = "defaultUser";
$accid = "Unknown";

$credits = "Not Applicable";

$avatarSmall = "smallUser"; //For Dashboard

} else {

include ('steamauth/userInfo.php');

$username = &$steamprofile['personaname'];
$avatar = &$steamprofile['avatarmedium'];
$accid = &$steamprofile['steamid'];

$avatarSmall = &$steamprofile['avatar']; //For Dashboard

$db_user = "USERNAME";
$db_pass = "PASSWORD";
$db_host = "HOST";
$db_name = "DATABASE NAME";

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$db_host.";db_name=".db_name, $db_user, $db_pass);

    try{
        $check = $db->prepare("SELECT userID from userData WHERE userID = :accountID");
        $check->bindParam(':accountID', $accid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $check->execute();
        if(!$check){
            die("Server Error: 404Check, Please Contact A Member Of Staff If This Error Continues.");
        }else{
            if($check->rowCount() > 0) {
                $creditsQuery = $db->prepare("SELECT userCredits FROM userData WHERE userID = :accountID3");
                $creditsQuery->bindParam(":accountID3", $accid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $creditsQuery->execute();
                //Set Credits To Variable From Database Column
                $credits = $creditsQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }else{
                $sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO userData (userID, userCredits) VALUES (:accountID2, '0')");
                $sql->bindParam(':accountID2', $accid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $sql->execute();
                if(!$sql){
                    die('Server Error: 404Insert, Please Contact A Member Of Staff If This Error Continues.');
                }
            }   
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die ("Server Error: 404Connection, Please Contact A Member Of Staff If This Error Continues.");
    }
}       

?>
```

Although, when I login, it doesn't seem to store the user's id or credits as 0, and the table (userData) is empty.

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
    $check->execute();
    if(!$check){
       ^^^^^^^
```

`$check` doesn't magically change into a boolean true/false if the execute fails. It will ALWAYS be a prepared statement object, and therefore always evaluate to `true`.

You didn't enable exceptions in PDO, therefore it runs in the default "return false on failure" mode, which means your code should be:

```
$res = $check->execute();
if(!$res) {
  die(...);
}
```

And this holds true for your other prepare/execute blocks as well - Your script is killing itself before it ever gets to the insert query, because your test for database failure is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, it seems the if statement is now running, although, the code it being killed, do you have any ideas why the query is failing?

Comment: no idea. even if your sql is 100% perfect/valid, there's any number of reasons for it to fail: foreign/unique key violation, db died, connection died, blah blah. you'll have to check why, e.g. `die($db->errorInfo())`

Comment: Ok, so the database successfully connects as the try block doesn't throw an exception although, it throws the error 404Check when i run the file at: [link](http://serverlauncherplus.co.uk/skins4accounts) once signed in. I can't think of any reason why $res isn't true.

Comment: then have the DB **TELL** you why it failed. issuing a 404 is a flat-out lie unless the db really did return a zero-record result set. `die($db->errorInfo())`

Comment: Sorry i also forgot to metion that returns 'Array'

Comment: ah. right. that returns an array. try `die(var_dump($db->errorInfo()))`

Comment: Alright, it returned array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }